# OpenGL textures trigger error 1281 and strange background behavior

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I am using SOIL to apply textures to VBOs, without textures i could change the background and display black (default color) vbos easily, but now with textures, openGL is giving an error 1281, the background is black and some textures are not applied. There must be something i didn't understand about applying/loading the textures. BUt the texture IS applied (nothing else is working though), the error is applied when i try to use the shader program however i checked the compilation of these and no problems were written.

Here is the code i use to load textures, once loaded it is kept in memory, it mostly comes from the example of SOIL :

```
    texture = SOIL_load_OGL_single_cubemap(
    filename,
    SOIL_DDS_CUBEMAP_FACE_ORDER,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
    SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO
    | SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS
    | SOIL_FLAG_DDS_LOAD_DIRECT
    );
if( texture > 0 )
{
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R );
    glTexGeni( GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP );
    glTexGeni( GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP );
    glTexGeni( GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_REFLECTION_MAP );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture );
    std::cout << "the loaded single cube map ID was " << texture << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Attempting to load as a HDR texture" << std::endl;
    texture = SOIL_load_OGL_HDR_texture(
        filename,
        SOIL_HDR_RGBdivA2,
        0,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO
        | SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS
        );
    if( texture < 1 )
    {
        std::cout << "Attempting to load as a simple 2D texture" << std::endl;
        texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
            filename,
            SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
            SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
            SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO
            | SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS
            | SOIL_FLAG_DDS_LOAD_DIRECT
            );
    }
    if( texture > 0 ) {
        //  enable texturing
        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        //  bind an OpenGL texture ID
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
        std::cout << "the loaded texture ID was " << texture << std::endl;
    } else {
        glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        std::cout << "Texture loading failed: '" << SOIL_last_result() << "'" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and how i apply it when drawing :

```
        GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "myTextureSampler");
    if(!TextureID)
        cout << "TextureID not found ..." << endl;
    // glEnableVertexAttribArray(TextureID);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    if(SFML)
        sf::Texture::bind(sfml_texture);
    else {
        glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        // glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1024, 768, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texture);
    }

    glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);
```

I am not sure that SOIL is adapted to my program as i want something as simple as possible (i used sfml's texture object which was the best but i can't anymore), but if i can get it to work it would be great.

EDIT :

After narrowing the code implied by the error, here is the code that provokes it, it is called between texture loading and bos drawing :

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
//this gives the error :
glUseProgram(this->shaderProgram);

if (!shaderLoaded)
{
    std::cout << "Loading default shaders" << std::endl;
    if(textured)
        loadShaderProgramm(texture_vertexSource, texture_fragmentSource);
    else
        loadShaderProgramm(default_vertexSource,default_fragmentSource);
}

glm::mat4 Projection = camera->getPerspective();

glm::mat4 View = camera->getView();
glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
Model[0][0] *= scale_x;
Model[1][1] *= scale_y;
Model[2][2] *= scale_z;

glm::vec3 translate_vec(this->x,this->y,this->z);
glm::mat4 object_transform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f),translate_vec);
glm::quat rotation = QAccumulative.getQuat(); 
glm::mat4 matrix_rotation = glm::mat4_cast(rotation);
object_transform *= matrix_rotation;
Model *= object_transform;

glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;  

GLuint ModelID = glGetUniformLocation(this->shaderProgram, "M");
if(ModelID ==-1)
    cout << "ModelID not found ..." << endl;
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(this->shaderProgram, "MVP");
if(MatrixID ==-1)
    cout << "MatrixID not found ..." << endl;
GLuint ViewID = glGetUniformLocation(this->shaderProgram, "V");
if(ViewID ==-1)
    cout << "ViewID not found ..." << endl;

glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelID, 1, GL_FALSE, &Model[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewID, 1, GL_FALSE, &View[0][0]);

drawObject();
```

Comment: 1281=0x501 which is GL_INVALID_VALUE, narrow down where the the error first triggers and then fix the previous glcall

Comment: @ratchetfreak ok i have done this, it comes from the glUseProgram call i did before, let me post the code, but without these textures my shaderprogram had no issue.

Comment: when i add the texture loading with SFML (and still use the texture of SOILF), the texture is displayed and there is no error so i guess that SFML does something that fixes it but i dont know what it is...

Comment: You'll probably want to load the shader program before calling `glUseProgram()`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi glUseProgram() is always called before, as i said the shader works fine but using the texture, it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, i used to disactivate the shader after drawing, in that method i had the call :

```
        sf::Texture::bind(NULL);
```

which somehow messed up the shaders too, i just commented this and now everything works fine